# How to set attributes with different names than a DB schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, orm

I am a newbie Ruby developer. I cannot figure out how to create an `ActiveRecord` model with different attributes names than defined in a DB schema

Consider the following schema

```
  create_table "sync_tasks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "path"
    t.string "task_type"
    t.string "status"
    t.boolean "async", default: false
    t.boolean "direct_download", default: true
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "completed_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

And I have the following payload

```
{
    "name" : "Sync /var/www/",
    "path" : "/var/www",
    "directDownload": true,
    "async" : false,
    "taskType" : "directory"
}
```

And trying to create my model like that

```
class SyncTask < ApplicationRecord
  TYPE_DB='db'
  TYPE_FILE='file'
  TYPE_DIRECTORY='directory'

  def initialize(params)
 #   super
    @task_type = params[:taskType]
    @direct_download = params[:directDownload]
    @path = params[:path]
    @status = params[:status]
    @async = params[:async]
  end
end
```

When I try to save it throws an error

```
<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>
```

Also I am not able to access field like that

```
  new_task = SyncTask.new(allowed_task_params)
  new_task.task_type
```

It throws the following error

```
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `task_type' for #<SyncTask not initialized>>
```

In case I uncomment the super call it gives another error

```
#<ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'taskType' for SyncTask.>
```

What I am doing wrong ? How can I use different attributes names and initialize the model by myself ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`transform the keys`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/Hash/transform_keys) , for example:

```
=> payload = { "name": "Sync /var/www/", "path": "/var/www", "directDownload": true, "taskType": "directory" }
=> h = payload.transform_keys { |key| key.to_s.underscore }  # only since v4.0.2
=> h = Hash[payload.map { |(k, v)| [k.to_s.underscore, v] }] # before v.4.0.2
#> {"name"=>"Sync /var/www/", "path"=>"/var/www", "direct_download"=>true, "task_type"=>"directory"}
=> new_task = SyncTask.new(h)
```

You shouldn't use the initialize method on AR models. If you still need to use `initialize`, use [`after_initialize`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find) hook. Because with the initialize we have to declare the super, so it is best to use the callback.

Comment: There is no way to provide custom initalizers at all ? I haven't expected such behavior from such dynamic language like Ruby

Comment: It works, but I don't like this solution, really poor functionality.

Comment: In this case you are dependent on model implementation details and you cannot separate different layers of your application, really disappointed

Comment: There are rules of Rails, if you don't like them, don't use Rails.

Comment: Interesting implementation, nevertheless thanks for the asnwer) spasibo :)